# Issue catching jQuery ajax exceptions

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I am trying to do is catch all errors and I handle myself.

But when and error occurs on jQuery.ajax() I can know if got error on the error options. But it is not being catchable by my window.onerror event.

```
window.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("i was here! ERROR: ", e);
    console.log("-----------");
    return true; //dont show errors on console
}

$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "asdasdasd/as/da/sdtest/asdasd",
        error: function() {
            // ok i know here is an error and it catches on my window.onerror. BUT look at your console, still have a GET error. That error I want to handle. Can be with try/catch or inside the window.onerror. I want that Exception object. Not this one that I created.
            throw new Error("it catches, but still have errors on my console");
        }
    });

    test[0].test = "it fails";

});
```

You can test over here: http://jsfiddle.net/uHPXm/4/

Comment: And what do you want to get? No `i was here! ERROR:  Uncaught Error: it catches, but still have errors on my console`? Or what?

Comment: Do you see this: GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/asdasdasd/as/da/sdtest/asdasd 404 (NOT FOUND). That is what i want to handle on my window.onerror, or inside a try/catch. I need the Exception object. The Stack is with this error. I want to get the StackTrace. And using the error function using mine throw new Error i cant

Answer (score 0):

The error function accepts three parameters, `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`

the jqXHR is the XMLHTTPRequest object, the textStatus it the string such as `timeout` or `abort` and the errorThrown is the raw error message, such as not found or internal sever error.

You can [Read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and head down to the `error` portion and read up more on it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

[document.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror)

> An event handler for runtime script errors.

In your case there is no runtime error in scripts. Scripts are Ok, but there is some error in request. Basically, no exception is thrown at all. Inside of jQuery there will be something like this (it is not from jquery code exactly, but it will be similar):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return

  if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      // Everything is ок
      ...
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      ...
  } else {
      handleError(xmlhttp.statusText) // Something went wrong, error handler called
  }
}

xmlhttp.send();


function handleError(message) {
      alert("Error: "+message)
}
```

Basically, 404 is not an exception for browser.

You may try to look at [jQuery.ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)
It will catch all errors happened in ajax requsts.

At the same time it may throw an error which will be catched by `window.onerror` if you will set `$.ajax({... dataType:'json'...})` and will get an HTML in response (error will happen while parsing response)